# Sharepoint 2010 Multilingual Issue

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have one issue in my sharepoint server 2010 multilingual issue..

Hindi language pack is available for windows server 2008 R2??
can i type letter and it convert to hindi or directly type in hindi language is possible in sharepoint server 2010??
My requirement is that m not able to use "Google translator"
I have to use Unicode for convert language 
Please help me to solve this issue..

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do translate text or just convert characters? Both has actually nothing to do, in this case, with Windows Server or SharePoint.

For SharePoint you can install the Hindi Language pack - that will make your SharePoint have all it's labels/UI in Hinid. Download it here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=046f16a9-4bce-4149-8679-223755560d54&displayLang=hi